# Flutter: Dismissible in PopupMenuButton does not risize while displayed

Tags: flutter, popupmenubutton, dismissible

I want to use a `Dismissible` Widget in a `PopupMenuButton` to delete items in the popup list.
My example code (see the example `main()` code below) works for deleting an item (String) in the PopupMenuButton, but the list is not refreshed and resized letting a blank space in the list while the popup is still displayed.
The list is only displayed resized  after the popup is closed and then reopened.
I remove the item from the list in a `setState` in the `onDismissed` callback so the widget tree should be rebuild.
How can I update and resize the displayed list in the popup without having to close and reopen it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter PopupMenuButton sample',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String dropdownValue = 'Orange';

  final _items = [
    'Orange',
    'Banana',
    'Grapes',
    'Apple',
    'watermelon',
    'Pineapple'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build Scaffold");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DropDownList Example"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("$dropdownValue"),
            const Spacer(),
            PopupMenuButton<String>(
              icon: Icon(Icons.bookmarks_outlined),
              onSelected: (String value) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownValue = value;
                });
                print(value);
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                return _items.map<PopupMenuItem<String>>((String _value) {
                  return PopupMenuItem(
                    value: _value,
                    child: Dismissible(
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                      onDismissed: (i) {
                        print("onDismissed $_value");
                        setState(() {
                          _items.remove(_value);
                        });
                      },
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(_value),
                        trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      ),
                      background: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.delete,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList();
              },
            ),
            const Spacer(
              flex: 10,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `PopupMenuButton` items create only while opening the menu items. I've tried with `StatefulBuilder` and `ValueNotifier` no result, also it is separated from context, you can try with different widget.

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh: yes, I am actually doing the equivalent with a ListView.builder with Dismissible's  in an AlertDialog and it seems to work. I will post the code when finished.